# Что означает знак вопроса в JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Есть такая строка. И я вообще не понимаю что она обозначает.

```
nr = (previous_number=='') ? 1 : parseInt(previous_number);
```

То есть, если previous_number является пустой строкой, перевести эту строку в целое число? зачем тогда единица делится на это целое число?

Извините, я в JavaScript совсем не разбираюсь и не могу найти...

Comment: А если прочитаете про [тернарный оператор](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/%D0%A3%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80), сможете сами ответить на свой вопрос?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Оператор представлен знаком вопроса ?. Его также называют «тернарный»,
> так как этот оператор, единственный в своём роде, имеет три аргумента.
>
> Синтаксис:
>
> ```
> let result = условие ? значение1 : значение2;
> ```
>
> Сначала вычисляется условие: если оно истинно, тогда возвращается
> значение1, в противном случае – значение2.

[Документация](https://learn.javascript.ru/ifelse)

---

В Вашем случае:

```
nr=(previous_number=='')?1:parseInt(previous_number);
```

т.е.:

```
let nr;
if(previous_number == ''){
  nr = 1;
}
else{ 
  nr = parseInt(previous_number);
}
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное. Я смотрела на это пару часов и не могла понять в чем дело.