# Объясните синтаксис

Tags: javascript

```
console.log(day=="Sunday" ? rules:"");
```

Самое короткое решение что я нашёл, но я не до конца понимаю что тут написано.

Comment: [Условный (тернарный) оператор](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Что означает знак вопроса в JavaScript?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1184189/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d0%b0-%d0%b2-javascript)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
console.log( day == "Sunday" ? rules : "" );
```

1. `day == "Sunday"` вернёт `true` или `false`;
2. [Тернарный оператор](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) при `true ? вернёт_это : ___`  , а при `false ? ___ : вернёт_это`;
3. `console.log` выведет в консоль то, что вернул тернарный оператор, то есть в данном случае `rules` или пустую строку.

Answer (score 1):

**В вашем примере тернарная условная операция**

```
условие ? выражение1 : выражение2
```

**условие** - ваш вопрос, допустим  `5 === 5`

**?** - Символ который как бы спрашивает, что `5 === 5 ?`

**`выражение1`** - Условная цифра/строка/переменная которая вернется в случае  `true`

**`выражение2`** - Условная цифра/строка/переменная которая вернется в случае  `false`

*В простом примере это конструкция  if / else, но короткая и от части удобная.*

Ваш пример можно переписать

---

```js
  if (day=="Sunday") { 
    rules;
  } 
  else { 
    ""; 
  } 
 

Но console.log() - возвращает результат метода.
```

Когда применять данный оператор?
В его применении вас никто не ограничивает, но лучше он подойдет, когда у вас есть простая конструкция.

---

```js
  const answer = 5+5 === 10 ? true : false;  
  console.log(answer);

  function getAnswer (d, b, c) { 
     return d + b === c ? c : d + b
  } 
  console.log(getAnswer(5,5,15)); 
  console.log(getAnswer(5,5,10));
```

Comment: первый пример неверен

Comment: @Grundy Уточни пожалуйста, условная конструкция  if/else  не верная, в каком месте, исправлюсь!

Comment: ты указываешь что, пример из вопроса можно переписать в виде `if`, но у предложенного тобой варианта, очевидно, другой результат, не соответствующий результату в вопросе.

Comment: Странно, я же просто переписал условие с одного оператора на другой, про  console.log дал пометку. Не понимаю где  ошибка...

Comment: В этом и ошибка.