# Python, Eel асинхронная функция возвращает [object Promise]

Tags: python, eel

Есть js код:

```
async function get_time() {
    let result = await eel.get_random_int();
    return result;
}
```

Эта функция возвращает случайное число из питона

```
@eel.expose
def get_random_int():
    return random.randint(0, 100)
```

Я читал документацию по eel, провёл больше шести часов в поисках решения ничего не нашел.

Может выведу вас на правильный путь: если вывести функцию через console.log, и всё выводится правильно так как и нужно, без ошибки "[object Promise]", а в html выводится из этой ошибкой, может вы тоже сталкивались из этим?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Любая `async function` всегда возвращает промис. Вам нужно дожидаться, когда в этом промисе появится значение, через then или await. И python здесь вообще ни при чём, это самые основы javascript

Comment: Спасибо, вывели меня на правильный путь, всё решил. @andreymal

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как вернуть значение из события или из функции обратного вызова? Или хотя бы дождаться их окончания](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/554290/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d0%98%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d1%85%d0%be%d1%82%d1%8f-%d0%b1%d1%8b-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b6)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Что означает знак вопроса в JavaScript?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1184189/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d0%b0-%d0%b2-javascript)